# Variables set to default values in closure

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've encountered rather weird behaviour of closures when using Spark 2.2.0. This program

```
object SparkConst extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("spark_const")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()


  val ctx = spark.sparkContext
  ctx.setLogLevel("WARN")

  val a = 2

  val xs = ctx.parallelize(Seq(1))

  val addValMap = xs.map(_ + a)

  println(s"Result ${addValMap.collect().mkString(",")}")
}
```

prints "Result 1" so `a` was equal to zero (default value) when `map` was evaluated. What am I doing wrong? How am I supposed to pass various constants to RDD transformations?

PS. The application is executed on YARN cluster in client mode.

Comment: This is common mistake. As the answer below states (from the official documentation) **that applications should define a main() method instead of extending scala.App. Subclasses of scala.App may not work correctly.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [Quick Start Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html)

> applications should define a main() method instead of extending scala.App. Subclasses of scala.App may not work correctly.

In practice, a lazy nature of `App` interacts with many features of Spark, including serialization and `Accumulators`.

So to fix this just rewrite your code to use standard `main`:

```
object SparkConst {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    ...
  }
}
```